# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related To ID - Allow activity Label Exception change?

Tags: apex, tasks

Morning,

I have a process that tries to provide a nice message when a user creates a task related to a custom object (MyObject__c) that hasn't got *Allow Activity* checkbox enabled. In order to do that, I try to identify Salesforce exception and if I get it, my process format it.

I have an org that is still on Winter'15 and the excepcion that I get is:

> First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION,
>   Opportunity/Account ID: id value of incorrect type:
>   a0Sw000000Nt4j9EAB: [WhatId]

However in a new org (Spring'15) the same execution returns a different error:

> First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION,
>   Related To ID: id value of incorrect type: a0S24000000HeEQEA0:
>   [WhatId]

I just wanted a confirmation about the label change from ***Opportunity/Account ID*** to ***Related To ID***

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got a response from Salesforce.

"This is because the Task 'WhatID' label has been changed to "Related To ID" in Spring 15 release.
Before the WhatID label is 'Opportunity/Account ID'. This is the reason for difference in error message.

We can see the whatid label has been changed in the below release notes:
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/pages/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm"

I hope this also helps others

Comment: Why don't you select your own answer as accepted one so that other can benefits ?

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed with my Full Sandbox updated to Spring'15 release, We now get Error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related To ID: id value of incorrect
>   type: a08q0000001Nbk9AAC: [WhatId]

Running the same code in Winter'15 shows following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Opportunity/Account ID: id value of
>   incorrect type: a08q0000001Nbk9AAC: [WhatId]

Sample code tried:

```
Task task = new Task();
task.WhatId = 'a0817000000IxxN'; // Id is valid but object but Activities disabled
task.WhoId = '00317000006nOUE';
task.Subject = 'Other';
task.status = 'Not Started';
task.description = 'New  Work';
insert task;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Custom Object, and check Allow Activities checkbox. This should solve your problem.

Comment: The question is asking about what the error message is if Activities have not been allowed for an object.